# internal error 500 with htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

after upload the htaccess file my website show the internal serever error 500...

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^deztimes\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://deztimes.com/$1 [R=301, L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/post/([^/]*)/size/([^/]*)/status/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&post=$2&size=$3&status=$4&title=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/post/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&post=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/size/([^/]*)/status/([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /?do=$1&size=$2&status=$3&id=$4&tite=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /?do=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/image/([^/]*)/size/([^/]*)/status/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&image=$2&size=$3&status=$4&title=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/image/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&image=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/height/([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&height=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /index.php?do=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?post=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

thanks

Comment: So read the error.log and find out what the error actually is.

Comment: And... what's the question? (Yes, we can guess, but it helps to be _clear_ with what you want help with.)

Comment: And what is the error?  Check your error log and add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the rewrite engine isn't so smart about whitespace, so whenever you have spaces it assumes you've got another parameter. So this line of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://deztimes.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

The rewrite engine sees the directive: `RewriteRule`, the first param (match) `(.*)` the second param (target) `http://deztimes.com/$1`, the third param (flags) `[R=301,` *and a fourth param* `L]`. You can technically have multiple flags as separate params but they need to be **enclosed by square brackets, [ ]**. The 2 flags that you have are not enclosed with square brackets. This is ok:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://deztimes.com/$1 [R=301] [L]
```

and this is OK:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://deztimes.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your solutions.with this belowe codes my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the exact same .htaccess in my docroot, and produced your error. After deleting the space from between the flags after the comma in your first RewriteRule, the error is gone.